# bash: ./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.1.1-online.run: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: command-line, nvidia, bash

I am trying to execute this .run file.
I did

```
sudo chmod +x ./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.1.1-online.run
./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.1.1-online.run
```

and got the following error

```
bash: ./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.1.1-online.run: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I am on a nvidia jetson nano running ubuntu 18.04
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: x64 is not what you really need on ARM board. Which Qt components do you really need to have?

Comment: There is a gui for windows that I need for my project andI have source code so I am porting it to linux. Someone used qt editor for this and was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt Creator is already [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qtcreator) for many CPU architectures including *armhf* and *arm64*.
To install it use commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful!