# bash: ./mmwave_sdk_02_00_00_04-Linux-x86-Install.bin: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: command-line, nvidia, bash

I am trying to execute this binary file.
I did

```
sudo chmod +x ./mmwave_sdk_02_00_00_04-Linux-x86-Install.bin
```

and got the following error

```
bash: ./mmwave_sdk_02_00_00_04-Linux-x86-Install.bin: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I am on a nvidia jetson nano running ubuntu 18.04. On the ti forum other people have had success with this version of ubuntu.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the output from the below to your answer:
file /bin/ls ; 
file mmwave_sdk_02_00_00_04-Linux-x86-Install.bin;
ldd mmwave_sdk_02_00_00_04-Linux-x86-Install.bin

Comment: Jetson Nanos are ARM-based, IIRC. Why are you running an x86 binary on it?

Comment: You just asked [essentially the same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342475/bash-qt-unified-linux-x64-4-1-1-online-run-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec) in relation to another software installation

Comment: @steeldriver yes but that was solved by not having to execute the file. this software has no alternative like the previous one did.

Comment: @muru that is the only file provided for linux.

Comment: @user10489 /bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=de05fcef79d88af9cf9a71ed38e73af0b179bfb2, stripped
mmwave_sdk_02_00_00_04-Linux-x86-Install.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped
 not a dynamic executable

Answer (score 3):

The architecture of the cpu and the executable don't match, this can not work without a virtual machine that supports cpu emulation, which may not be performant and might not exist.

You will need to either get a Jetson compatible version of this, recompile it, run it in a x86 compatible virtual machine (which likely would be slow), or run this on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

As @user10489 mentioned the mmWave SDK is provided for x86 arch (both linux and windows), so won't be able to install it on jetson, as TI don't provide full code.

However, you most probably don't need to install the SDK on the jetson as it is only needed to flush the radar MSS (which can be done at a different machine in the lab), interfacing the radar is done either via serial or ethernet (DCA1000), neither requiring the SDK.

See the [ti ros node](https://git.ti.com/cgit/?q=mmwave) on how to extract pointclouds, and see the CLI application (inside the mmWaveStudio install folder / mmWaveStudio/ReferenceCode/DCA1000) on how to extract raw data.